# Double Click Crypto in Golang

Tags: go

doc: https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-price#sample_code

There is no official "Double Click Crypto" example code in golang, so I try to implement by myself. But I can't pass the test in doc. Please help me!

```
skU7Ax_NL5pPAFyKdkfZjZz2-VhIN8bjj1rVFOaJ_5o=  // Encryption key (e_key)

arO23ykdNqUQ5LEoQ0FVmPkBd7xB5CO89PDZlSjpFxo=  // Integrity key (i_key)

WEp8wQAAAABnFd5EkB2k1wJeFcAj-Z_JVOeGzA  // 100 CPI micros

WEp8sQAAAACwF6CtLJrXSRFBM8UiTTIyngN-og  // 1900 CPI micros

WEp8nQAAAAADG-y45xxIC1tMWuTjzmDW6HtroQ  // 2700 CPI micros
```

Here is my code:

```
package main

// https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-price?hl=zh-CN

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

var base64Codec = base64.URLEncoding.WithPadding(base64.NoPadding)

func safeXORBytes(dst, a, b []byte) int {
    n := len(a)
    if len(b) < n {
        n = len(b)
    }
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        dst[i] = a[i] ^ b[i]
    }
    return n
}

func EncryptPrice(eKey []byte, iKey []byte, price uint64, iv []byte) (finalMessage string, err error) {
    if len(iv) != 16 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("len(iv) = %d != 16", len(iv))
        return
    }

    h1 := hmac.New(sha1.New, eKey)
    h1.Write(iv)
    pad := h1.Sum(nil)[:8]

    priceBytes := make([]byte, 8)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(priceBytes, price)

    encPrice := make([]byte, 8)
    n := safeXORBytes(encPrice, priceBytes, pad)
    if n != 8 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("safeXORBytes n != %d", n)
        return
    }

    h2 := hmac.New(sha1.New, iKey)
    h2.Write(priceBytes)
    h2.Write(iv)
    signature := h2.Sum(nil)[:4]

    finalMessage = base64Codec.EncodeToString(append(append(iv, encPrice...), signature...))
    return
}

func DecryptPrice(eKey []byte, iKey []byte, finalMessage string) (price uint64, err error) {
    finalMessageBytes, err := base64Codec.DecodeString(finalMessage)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    if len(finalMessageBytes) != 28 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("len(finalMessageBytes) = %d != 28", len(finalMessageBytes))
        return
    }

    iv := finalMessageBytes[:16]
    encPrice := finalMessageBytes[16:24]
    signature := finalMessageBytes[24:]

    h1 := hmac.New(sha1.New, eKey)
    h1.Write(iv)
    pad := h1.Sum(nil)[:8]

    priceBytes := make([]byte, 8)
    n := safeXORBytes(priceBytes, encPrice, pad)
    if n != 8 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("safeXORBytes n != %d", n)
        return
    }

    h2 := hmac.New(sha1.New, iKey)
    h2.Write(priceBytes)
    h2.Write(iv)
    confSignature := h2.Sum(nil)[:4]

    if bytes.Compare(confSignature, signature) != 0 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("sinature mismatch: confSignature = %s, sinature = %s", confSignature, signature)
        return
    }

    price = binary.BigEndian.Uint64(priceBytes)
    return
}
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "testing"
)

func TestEncryptPrice(t *testing.T) {
    eKeyBase64Encoded := "skU7Ax_NL5pPAFyKdkfZjZz2-VhIN8bjj1rVFOaJ_5o"
    eKey, err := base64Codec.DecodeString(eKeyBase64Encoded)
    assert.Nil(t, err)

    iKeyBase64Encoded := "arO23ykdNqUQ5LEoQ0FVmPkBd7xB5CO89PDZlSjpFxo"
    iKey, err := base64Codec.DecodeString(iKeyBase64Encoded)
    assert.Nil(t, err)

    finalMessage, err := EncryptPrice(eKey, iKey, uint64(100), []byte{88, 74, 124, 193, 0, 0, 0, 0, 103, 21, 222, 68, 144, 29, 164, 215})
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, "WEp8wQAAAABnFd5EkB2k1wJeFcAj-Z_JVOeGzA", finalMessage)
}

func TestDecryptPrice(t *testing.T) {
    eKeyBase64Encoded := "skU7Ax_NL5pPAFyKdkfZjZz2-VhIN8bjj1rVFOaJ_5o"
    eKey, err := base64Codec.DecodeString(eKeyBase64Encoded)
    assert.Nil(t, err)

    iKeyBase64Encoded := "arO23ykdNqUQ5LEoQ0FVmPkBd7xB5CO89PDZlSjpFxo"
    iKey, err := base64Codec.DecodeString(iKeyBase64Encoded)
    assert.Nil(t, err)

    price, err := DecryptPrice(eKey, iKey, "WEp8wQAAAABnFd5EkB2k1wJeFcAj-Z_JVOeGzA")
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, uint64(100), price)
}
```

---

test result:

```
--- FAIL: TestEncryptPrice (0.00s)
        Error Trace:    price_test.go:19
    Error:          Not equal:
                    expected: "WEp8wQAAAABnFd5EkB2k1wJeFcAj-Z_JVOeGzA"
                    actual: "WEp8wQAAAABnFd5EkB2k1wf7jAcG7gZ9tPUnAA"
--- FAIL: TestDecryptPrice (0.00s)
        Error Trace:    price_test.go:32
    Error:          Expected nil, but got: &errors.errorString{s:"sinature mismatch: confSignature = \xbe\xaa\xf6h, sinature = T\xe7\x86\xcc"}
        Error Trace:    price_test.go:33
    Error:          Not equal:
                    expected: 0x64
                    actual: 0x0
FAIL
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting votes to close due to lack of mcve, when this is precisely a Minimal (short of making it non-functional), Complete (it even has the test data from the documentation), Verifiable Example, nicely wrapped in a test fixture. @小明湖畔, I don't see what you're missing from the docs. If someone has time to step through the java library, I guessing there's some discrepancy between that and the pseudocode.

Comment: Based on how `finalMessage` is produced in `EncryptPrice`, and on the fact that the real and expected base64-encodings of that "encrypted price" thing differ exactly in their trailers, I'd say that supposedly the encoded price and may be IV are correct, but the signature is not.

Answer (score 0):

this code can pass the test in https://github.com/google/openrtb-doubleclick/blob/0.9.0/doubleclick-core/src/test/java/com/google/doubleclick/crypto/DoubleClickCryptoTest.java
, so I guess that the encrypted price in the doc are not excrypted by the e_key and i_key in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today. Finally, I found the bug was that '`ekey`' and '`ikey`' did not need to `base64Codec.DecodeString`, just use []byte(eKeyBase64Encoded).

```
eKeyBase64Encoded := "skU7Ax_NL5pPAFyKdkfZjZz2-VhIN8bjj1rVFOaJ_5o"
eKey := []byte(eKeyBase64Encoded)
assert.Nil(t, err)

iKeyBase64Encoded := "arO23ykdNqUQ5LEoQ0FVmPkBd7xB5CO89PDZlSjpFxo"
iKey :=[]byte(iKeyBase64Encoded)
assert.Nil(t, err)

price, err := DecryptPrice(eKey, iKey, "WEp8wQAAAABnFd5EkB2k1wJeFcAj-Z_JVOeGzA")
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The encrypted price that are listed in this document https://developers.google.com/authorized-buyers/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-price have been encoded using the keys they showed above the prices. The examples are correct. I wrote a small Go package that provides a Decrypt function, I might add an encrypt one soon: https://github.com/matipan/doubleclick. Below I leave an example and code snippets for easy access.

First, to be able to parse the keys we need to respect the web-safe base64 decoding, which means we need to use [base64.URLEncoding](https://pkg.go.dev/base64#URLEncoding)! to decode the keys:

```golang
// ParseKeys parses the base64 web-safe encoded keys as explained in Google's documentation:
// https://developers.google.com/authorized-buyers/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-price
func ParseKeys(ic, ec []byte) (icKey []byte, ecKey []byte, err error) {
    icKey = make([]byte, base64.URLEncoding.DecodedLen(len([]byte(ic))))
    n, err := base64.URLEncoding.Decode(icKey, []byte(ic))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("%w: could not decode price integrity key", err)
    }

    icKey = icKey[:n]

    ecKey = make([]byte, base64.URLEncoding.DecodedLen(len([]byte(ec))))
    n, err = base64.URLEncoding.Decode(ecKey, []byte(ec))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("%w: could not decode price encryption key", err)
    }

    ecKey = ecKey[:n]

    return icKey, ecKey, nil
}
```

We can call this code and decrypt the keys they show:

```golang
    icKey, ecKey, err = ParseKeys([]byte("arO23ykdNqUQ5LEoQ0FVmPkBd7xB5CO89PDZlSjpFxo="), []byte("skU7Ax_NL5pPAFyKdkfZjZz2-VhIN8bjj1rVFOaJ_5o="))
```

The function to decrypt the price with a bit more error handling is:

```golang
// ErrInvalidPrice is the error returned when the price parsed
// by DecryptPrice is not correct.
var ErrInvalidPrice = errors.New("price is invalid")

// DecryptPrice decrypts the price with google's doubleclick cryptography encoding.
// encPrice is an unpadded web-safe base64 encoded string according to RFC 3548.
// https://developers.google.com/authorized-buyers/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-price
func DecryptPrice(icKey, ecKey, encPrice []byte) (uint64, error) {
    if len(icKey) == 0 || len(ecKey) == 0 {
        return 0, errors.New("encryption and integrity keys are required")
    }

    if len(encPrice) != 38 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("%w: invalid length, expected 28 got %d", ErrInvalidPrice, len(encPrice))
    }

    dprice := make([]byte, base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodedLen(len(encPrice)))
    n, err := base64.RawURLEncoding.Decode(dprice, encPrice)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("%w: invalid base64 string", err)
    }
    dprice = dprice[:n]

    if len(dprice) != 28 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("%w: invalid decoded price length. Expected 28 got %d", ErrInvalidPrice, len(dprice))
    }

    // encrypted price is composed of parts of fixed lenth. We break it up according to:
    // {initialization_vector (16 bytes)}{encrypted_price (8 bytes)}{integrity (4 bytes)}
    iv, p, sig := dprice[0:16], dprice[16:24], dprice[24:]
    h := hmac.New(sha1.New, ecKey)
    n, err = h.Write(iv)
    if err != nil || n != len(iv) {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("%w: could not write hmac hash for iv. err=%s, n=%d, len(iv)=%d", ErrInvalidPrice, err, n, len(iv))
    }
    pricePad := h.Sum(nil)

    price := safeXORBytes(p, pricePad)
    if price == nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("%w: price xor price_pad failed", ErrInvalidPrice)
    }

    h = hmac.New(sha1.New, icKey)
    n, err = h.Write(price)
    if err != nil || n != len(price) {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("%w: could not write hmac hash for price. err=%s, n=%d, len(price)=%d", ErrInvalidPrice, err, n, len(price))
    }

    n, err = h.Write(iv)
    if err != nil || n != len(iv) {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("%w: could not write hmac hash for iv. err=%s, n=%d, len(iv)=%d", ErrInvalidPrice, err, n, len(iv))
    }

    confSig := h.Sum(nil)[:4]
    if bytes.Compare(confSig, sig) != 0 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("%w: integrity of price is not valid", ErrInvalidPrice)
    }

    return binary.BigEndian.Uint64(price), nil
}

func safeXORBytes(a, b []byte) []byte {
    n := len(a)
    if len(b) < n {
        n = len(b)
    }

    if n == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    dst := make([]byte, n)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        dst[i] = a[i] ^ b[i]
    }

    return dst
}
```

We can now call this code using the example of 1900 micros: `YWJjMTIzZGVmNDU2Z2hpN7fhCuPemC32prpWWw`:

```
price, err := DecryptPrice(icKey, ecKey, []byte("YWJjMTIzZGVmNDU2Z2hpN7fhCuPemC32prpWWw"))
```

And price will be 1900